# How can I know if the characters of a string repeat themselves the same amount of times when they have a wildcard built-in?

Tags: javascript, arrays, character, wildcard

examples:

- `testing("xyzy**")` should be `true`.
- `testing("xyzy*")` should be `false`.

Reasoning:

- In the first case, it is true because one `*` can behave as a `x` and the other a `z`, so all characteres would of the same amount of `y`.
- In the second case there wouldn't be the same amount of characters repeating itself, cause there is only one `*`, so it is false.

Here is what I have up until now:

```
const testing = string => {
    var array = []; //array with each character without repeating
    var array_R = []; //array with the value the value that each character repeats itself
    var array_C = 0; //counter for the size of "array"
    
    //getting the character without repeating
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      if (!array.includes(string.charAt(i))) {
        array[array_C] = string.charAt(i);
        array_R[array_C] = 0;
        array_C++;
      }
    }
    
    //how many each character repeats itself
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
        if(array[i] == string.charAt(j)){
          array_R[i] = array_R[i] + 1;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I really don't know how I can proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First count up the number of occurrences of each non-`*` character into an object or Map. Find the maximum value in that collection, then find the sum of all differences between the maximum value and each value. If the number of asterisks is the same as the sum of differences, the repeat conditions are fulfilled.

You'll also have to consider the case where there are more asterisks left over after all holes are filled in to make the values equal - figure out how many are left over, and see if that evenly divides the number of separate characters.

```js
const testing = (str) => {
  const grouped = {};
  for (const char of str) {
    if (char !== '*') grouped[char] = (grouped[char] || 0) + 1;
  }
  const values = Object.values(grouped);
  const numOfSeparateChars = values.length;
  const max = Math.max(...values);
  const sum = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  const sumOfDifferencesFromMax = max * numOfSeparateChars - sum;
  const numberAsterisks = (str.match(/\*/g) || []).length;
  const remainingAsterisks = sumOfDifferencesFromMax - numberAsterisks;
  // Now all characters have been filled in to make the values even
  // eg: 'abcc**' -> 'abccab'
  // But there may be more asterisks
  // eg: 'abcc*****' -> 'abccaabbc'
  return remainingAsterisks % numOfSeparateChars === 0;
};
console.log(testing("xyzy**"));
console.log(testing("xyzy*"));
```